# Is there any list of english stop words for blogs?

Tags: nlp, web-crawler, stop-words

I am working on blogs to analyses their content. I am using basic english stop word list but it is not enough because of blog specific frequent but useless words like "archive", "comment" and such. Do you know pre-created list of stop-words targeting blogs?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any such resource. The best way to go about it would be to compute the top (say 1000) most frequent words from the document collection and set a subset (say 200) of them as stopwords. You might also vary this cut-off parameter (say 100 or 300 instead of 200) to see the effect on retrieval performance.

Comment: Also consider using (for example) tf-idf or log entropy, as some frequent words might still be considered useful for analysis.